# Appending text to Html.fromHtml

Tags: android, html

I haev html attributions that are in this format:

```
 <a href="https://www.example.com/">Example Company</a>
```

Now, I have successfully made a textview clickable so that if the user click on this textview, the user is redirected to the link.

However, I want the user to know that this is attribution so I want to setText with the word "Attribution: " before the html attribution. In other words, I want to do this:

```
attribution.setText("Attribution: " + Html.fromHtml("HTML ATTRIBUTION TEXT"));
```

And I want the end results to be this:

```
Attribution: Example Company
```

As soon as I add on the word "Attribution: " before my html link, the link is no longer clickable.

I know an easy way to fix this is to create two textviews, one containing the word "Attribution: " and the other containing the html and put them next to one another but was wondering if there is a way to append words to an html link and still keep the link clickable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #1: Put `"Attribution: "` in the HTML.

Option #2: [Use `TextUtils.concat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#concat%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29).

Option #3: Dump the HTML and build up your whole value using a `SpannableStringBuilder`.